# Rearrange columns into a txt file c#

Tags: c#, streamwriter

I have multiple columns and I want to reordered into a txt file, so far the first column is inserted right but I want the next ones to be on the side, they keep writing at the end.
This is what I have so far

```
StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(file.FullName, System.Text.Encoding.GetEncoding("iso-8859-1"));
List <Campos> listaEsquemaEntrada = LeerXML(RutaArchivoConfig);
var lista = File.ReadAllLines(file.FullName);           
string Separador = ObtenerSeparador(RutaArchivoConfig);
int filaInicial = ObtenerLineaInicial(RutaArchivoConfig);
List<string> ListaFinal = new List<string>();
bool PrimeraIteracion = true;
foreach (Campos campos in listaEsquemaEntrada)
{
    if (campos.columna != 99)
    {
        using (System.IO.StreamWriter ArchivoSalida =
                new System.IO.StreamWriter(RutaOrigen + "\\" + "nuevoArchivo.txt",true))
        {
            if (PrimeraIteracion)
            {
                foreach (string line in lista)
                {
                    ArchivoSalida.WriteLine(line.Split(Char.Parse(Separador))[campos.columna - 1]);
                }
                PrimeraIteracion=false;
            }
            else
            {
                foreach (string line in lista)
                {
                    ArchivoSalida.WriteLine(Separador + line.Split(Char.Parse(Separador))[campos.columna - 1]);
                }
            }
           
        }
    }
    else
    {
        continue;
    }
}
```

But i keep getting this

```
C�digo de la Cuenta Contable 
111100101   
111150012   
111150016   
111150028   
111150039   
116150101   
116150101   
|Tipo de Comprobante 
|APE
|APE
```

i want something like this :

```
C�digo de la Cuenta Contable |Tipo de Comprobante
111100101   |APE
111150012   |APE
111150016   |APE
111150028   |APE
111150039   |APE
116150101   |APE
116150101   |APE
```

Comment: WriteLine appends a newline to your output. You need to use Write and when a line is finished you can call WriteLine empty to start the new row

Comment: Its an iteration, the first column is inserted and the second is after the entire first is there, i dont insert one cell at the time, i already try the Write method one the second foreach but it still going at the bottom of the first one

Comment: Thats what i want, write the first column entirely, and after that write the second plus a separator that in this case is | , i cant write line by line, because im getting the positions from an xml with the columns that i want to get and transfer to the txt, basicaly i have a txt with multiple columns, i want to select just a few and write them into a new txt file, maybe theres another approach to this that im not able to see

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yep, that's how text files work. If you've written a single column to a text file:

```
var first = new [] { "header", "line1", "line2", "line3" };
File.WriteAllLines(@"c:\temp\file.txt", first);
```

And you want to write another column

```
var second = new [] { "header2", "newline1", "newline2", "newline3" };
```

It's probably simplest to just read the entire file, add each new bit onto the end of each line, and write the whole file again:

```
var file = File.ReadAllLines(@"c:\temp\file.txt");
for(int i = 0; i < file.Length; i++)
  file[i] += '\t' + second[i]; //add the second column after the first, with a tab

File.WriteAllLines(@"c:\temp\file.txt", file);
```

Of course, if you have both `first` and `second` (as `List`s, arrays, `IEnumerable<string>` etc) before you even write the file the first time, just do the combine then; no need to re-read the file. I just put that in if you're looking to have a process that modifies an existing file written before (eg yesterday, when you didn't have the second column of data)

If your file is massive, you can get more involved with having a gradual read of one file (see `File.ReadLines` instead), and a gradual write of another file (`StreamWriter` etc), so you aren't buffering the whole thing into memory.. But if youre talking about a file that is less than, say, 10 megabytes, go for the simple approach and just read it all, modify, write it all

Comment: the problem is that the number of column its variable, sometimes i need to get 3 columns in diferent positions and after that i maybe gonna need 2 columns in another positions, i cant declare arrays because i cant know how many or where the columns are gonna be

Comment: Then you need to read the file, split on tabs, rearrange the columns when you write it out. I can only answer the scenario as presented in the question. I just declared arrays as an example; you have lists - they can be passed into WriteAllLines. You're missing the major point I'm making: If you want a text file to be a different shape, you read it all, create a new file that is the new shape by mixing old data and new, and write it again. If you're trying to reinvent a database, there are better ways.. Like using a database

Comment: `StringBuilder` would be preferable over concatenation if it's a large file.

Comment: If it's a large file, it'll be incremental read write; there wouldn't be any need for a string builder or string concat for that matter; you'd just write strings in the relevant order.  At best a stringbuilder represents a marginal improvement, but moreover it is completely ancillary to the point this answer makes